# Php websocket why ord in frame decoding?

Tags: php, websocket, frame, decoding, ord

I'm trying to understand Websockets protocol and I'm stuck in frame decoding part. In every PHP example I saw, I saw the use of the "ord" function and when I'm looking at the doc (in French actually), it says that it returns the ASCII value of a character. But when I'm looking at the [RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5) (Payload length), it says "not ASCII characters".

I saw this [link](https://igor.io/2012/09/24/binary-parsing.html) to drop down to the binary level, it returns values like "-20165154".
And with this example "[link](https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat/blob/master/class.PHPWebSocket.php)", I'm completely lost now.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you give an example of the input, the expected output, and what you've tried ?